# Can Alloy generate instances of unconstrained relations?

Tags: alloy

The following model contains a "run" command that instructs the Alloy Analyzer to generate an instance of the relation `to.address`, where the relation is constrained to exactly one tuple.

```
sig Message {
    to: Name
}

sig Name {
    address: Address
}

sig Address {}  

run {one to.address}
```

But I don't want to constrain the `to.address` relation. I would like to simply write this:

```
run {to.address}
```

*Hey Alloy Analyzer, generate an instance of the relation `to.address`*

Executing that run command results in this error message: `{to.address} must be a formula.`

Is there a way to instruct the Alloy Analyzer to generate an instance of the relation `to.address` without specifying a constraint on the relation? If not, why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding what the visualizer does. Each execution of Alloy generates an instance that binds all relations. The body of the run command is a constraint that determines which instances are valid; it has no effect on *which* relations are displayed. To do what you want, you can write a constraint that names the relation (eg with an existential quantifier). Or if you want to see the value of a particular expression, you can just type it into the evaluator.